# How to set PHP set_error_handler correctly

Tags: php, error-handling, custom-error-handling

Can you help me please to set php **set_error_handler** correctly? I need to handle the code which throws php **warning as exception**. But I don't know how to do it properly. Now I have this code, which I think is not correct.

```
set_error_handler( function( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext )
{
    throw new \Exception( $errstr, $errno );
});
$mailer->send( $mail );
restore_error_handler();
```

As I have seen in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#112881) it needs more complex solution. But I am little confused about all that constants. 
Is there a way to set it in some elegant way which wont set up all the constants separately. 
I mean something like:

```
function( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext )
{
    if( $errno >= E_USER_WARNING ) throw new \Exception( $errstr, $errno );
});
```

So how to include php warnings to Exception in some elegant way. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case there has to bee a condition for errno and it has to return true.

```
set_error_handler( function( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext )
{
    // Cause Php does not catch stream_socket_client warnings message.
    if ( $errno == E_WARNING ) throw new \Exception( $errstr, $errno ); 
    // Is necessary to handle other errors by default handler.
    return true; 
});
```